# Emitting back to parent does not work with v-model in Vue3

Tags: arrays, vuejs3, eventemitter, v-model

Emitting from child to parent in Vue 3 component with v-model does not work. The v-model value from the parent does come through the child but not the other way around. So emitting from the child to the parent does not work.

Someone can tell what is wrong?

Btw if I send the value as a regular prop then emit works. So

The parent template with the v-model:

```
   <Item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id" v-model:item="items[index]">
        <template v-slot:button>
          <div class="button">
            <label for="item-select">
              <select v-model="item.quantity" name="item-select">
                <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.value" :value="option.value">
                  {{ option.text }}
                </option>
              </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        </template>
      </Item>
```

The child component:

```
<template>
  <div data-cy="item" class="item-wrapper">
    <img :src="itemRef.image_url" :alt="itemRef.title" />
    <div class="info-box">
      <h2 class="title">{{ itemRef.title}}</h2>
      <p class="price">Price: <span>{{ itemRef.price }} €</span></p>
      <p class="stock">In stock: <span>{{ itemRef.stock_quantity}}</span></p>
      <p class="quantity">Quantity: <span> {{ itemRef.quantity }}</span></p>
      <slot name="button"></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import {
  defineComponent, PropType, toRef, onUpdated,
} from 'vue'
import { Book } from '@/composables/useItems'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ItemComponent',
  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object as PropType<Book>,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  emits: ['update:item'],
  setup(props, context) {
    const itemRef = toRef(props, 'item')

    onUpdated(() => {
      context.emit('update:item', itemRef.value)
    })
    return { itemRef }
  },
})
</script>
```

Comment: Could you make a working demo on stackblitz.com or codesandbox.io to reproduce your problem?

Comment: you do not have to do it like that anymore. https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3